# React - Render component based on a generated random hash

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to render a component based on an hash that is generated on a click event.

Simple case : I'm on my `localhost:3000` and i got a button that generate a room on my backend with a random hash and for front, i'd like to render my `lobby` component with the url being `localhost:3000/#randomhash`. So far I generate the url with `window.location.hash` but I've no idea how to make him render the `lobby` with my route

app.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
           <Route exact path='/' element={<Menu />}></Route>
          <Route path='/:roomId' element={<Lobby />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

menu.js

```js
const socket = socketIO.connect('http://localhost:4000');

const Menu = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('lobbyJoined', (...args) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(args[0]);
            //data.id is my generated hash (#fs42f for example)
            window.location.hash = data.id;
        });

        return () => {
            socket.off('lobbyJoined');
        };
    }, []);

    return(
        <>
            <div className='Menu'>
               //button to join a lobby triggering my socket event
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

and my index.js

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

details:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.2",
  },
```

Comment: In `HashRouter`s the route ***is*** the hash, i.e. `localhost:3000/#/randomhash` is route `path="/randomhash"`. You may want to use one of the other high-level routers or use a queryString for the room number.